I want to keep the same ratio for the pictures in this astro.build component
The ratio of the picture for this component when the width of the browser becomes less than 1178 pixels, then it changes ratio from 9:16 (Vertical) to 16:9 (Horizontal). However, I tried to see how I can solve it, but I just cannot find it and I already spent a full day on it so I'm desperate here.
I will paste in the different scripts I tried to change, including the tailwind classes, adding React, etc. but nothing worked so far. It must be something simple I cannot see. I'm using this theme:
https://astro.build/themes/details/screwfast/
And it's the FeaturesNavs.astro file that is not letting me change what I need.
FeaturesNavs.astro:
---
// Import the necessary dependencies
import TabNav from "@components/ui/blocks/TabNav.astro";
import TabContent from "@components/ui/blocks/TabContent.astro";
import Icon from "@components/ui/icons/Icon.astro";

// Define props from Astro
const { title, tabs } = Astro.props;

// Define TypeScript interface for tab object
interface Tab {
  heading: string;
  content: string;
  svg: string;
  src: any;
  alt: string;
  first?: boolean;
  second?: boolean;
}

// Define TypeScript interface for props
interface Props {
  title?: string;
  tabs: Tab[];
}
---

<section
  class="mx-auto max-w-[85rem] px-4 py-10 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 lg:py-14 2xl:max-w-full"
>
  <div class="relative p-6 md:p-16">
    <div
      class="relative z-10 lg:grid lg:grid-cols-12 lg:items-center lg:gap-16"
    >
      <!-- Section's heading and tab navigation -->
      <div class="mb-10 lg:order-2 lg:col-span-6 lg:col-start-8 lg:mb-0">
        <h2
          class="text-2xl font-bold text-neutral-800 dark:text-neutral-200 sm:text-3xl"
        >
          <!-- About Fragment: https://docs.astro.build/en/basics/astro-syntax/#fragments -->
          <Fragment set:html={title} />
        </h2>
        <!-- Tab navigation - use the attribute 'first' in the first TabNav for the component to work -->
        <nav class="mt-5 grid gap-4 md:mt-10" aria-label="Tabs" role="tablist">
          {
            tabs.map((tab, index) => (
              <TabNav
                id={`tabs-with-card-item-${index + 1}`}
                dataTab={`#tabs-with-card-${index + 1}`}
                aria={`tabs-with-card-${index + 1}`}
                heading={tab.heading}
                content={tab.content}
                first={tab.first}
              >
                <Icon name={tab.svg} />
              </TabNav>
            ))
          }
        </nav>
      </div>

      <!-- Contents for each tab - the 'first' attribute should be used in the first tab for that tab to be initially visible, 'second' changes the styles -->
      <div class="lg:col-span-6">
        <div class="relative">
          <div>
            {
              tabs.map((tab, index) => (
                <TabContent
                  id={`tabs-with-card-${index + 1}`}
                  aria={`tabs-with-card-item-${index + 1}`}
                  src={tab.src}
                  alt={tab.alt}
                  first={tab.first}
                  second={tab.second}
                />
              ))
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="absolute inset-0 grid h-full w-full grid-cols-12">
      <!-- Decorative background and sizing -->
      <div
        class="col-span-full h-5/6 w-full rounded-xl bg-neutral-100 dark:bg-white/[.075] sm:h-3/4 lg:col-span-7 lg:col-start-6 lg:h-full"
      >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!--Import the necessary Tabs plugin-->
<!--https://preline.co/plugins/html/tabs.html-->
<script>
  import "@preline/tabs/index.js";
</script>

TabContent.astro:
---
// Import the Image component from astro:assets
import { Image } from "astro:assets";

// Destructure the component properties from Astro.props
const { id, aria, src, alt, first, second } = Astro.props;

// Define TypeScript interface for the properties
interface Props {
  id: string;
  aria: string;
  src?: any;
  alt: string;
  first?: boolean;
  second?: boolean;
}
// Set class based on 'first' property
// If 'first' is present, show the tab content immediately
const firstClass = first ? "" : "hidden";
// Set class based on 'second' property
// If 'second' is present, use an alternate style for the image
const secondClass = second
  ? "shadow-xl aspect-[5/4] bg-neutral-300 dark:bg-neutral-600 object-cover p-3 lg:aspect-auto shadow-neutral-200 rounded-xl dark:shadow-neutral-900/[.2]"
  : "shadow-xl aspect-[3/2] object-cover lg:aspect-auto shadow-neutral-200 rounded-xl dark:shadow-neutral-900/[.2]";

/*
first: This property should be set to true for the initial TabContent component
in your list to ensure that it's visible when the page first loads.
All subsequent TabContent components should omit this property or set it to false.

second: This property allows to control changes in the look of the Image.
If it is set to true, the Image will have different aspect ratio and background color.
If this property is not provided or is set to false, the Image will use default styling.
You can enable this for any TabContent component you want to apply these changes to.

This is the full example:
<TabContent id="" aria="" src="" alt="" first={true}/>
<TabContent id="" aria="" src="" alt="" second={true}/>
<TabContent id="" aria="" src="" alt="" />
*/
---

<!-- Container for tab content that controls visibility and accessibility -->
<div id={id} role="tabpanel" class={firstClass} aria-labelledby={aria}>
  <!-- Astro Image component to display the image with dynamic classes based on the 'second' property -->
  <Image
    src={src}
    alt={alt}
    class={secondClass}
    draggable={"false"}
    format={"avif"}
    loading={"eager"}
  />
</div>

